# Murmur3_128 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, hash, cryptography, murmurhash

I struggle with finding a way to produce a HASH in javascript that would be equivalent to one produced in java with this code

```
private static final HashFunction MURMUR_3_128 = Hashing.murmur3_128(SEED);

public static String hash(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return MURMUR_3_128.hashUnencodedChars(string).toString();
}
```

Does anybody have a clue if I can produce the same HASH in javascript as the one produced from this kind of code in java?? I can't find anything that would allow me to get the same results..

Comment: I added the relevant tag. Maybe any of the existing anwers that you find when you click on the tag helps